# Are There any folder name that are not allowed in artifactory or npm?

Tags: npm, directory, publish, artifactory, npm-publish

I have an npm package to publish to a artifactory server. One of the folders in the package is named `test`. It contains necessary test scripts.The problem is the test folder will not be available in the package (the remainder of the package is unaffected). When the folder is renamed , it is published with all its content. So is there any restriction in using test as a folder name. Also are there any other names that are restricted by npm/artifactory.

Comment: Considering it has to store files on disk, probably the same limitation as the underlying OS files

Comment: How does that restrict the scope of naming?

Comment: For example, filenames can not have /

Comment: True.But filenames are not restricted for alphanumeric characters as it is in this case.

Comment: I didn't say they were. If you think some characters are a problem, why can't you just try uploading them to Artifactory?

Comment: I have already attempted to upload. Please understand the question.

Comment: I understand your question fine